# Leaving an Area of Specialization (AOS) off of my CV?

Tags: ethics, cv

So with the job market being as it is, I'm considering the prospect of leaving academia after my PhD. The problem that I have is that the name of one of my Areas of Specialization has been co-opted by some new age mystics and if you search "X" after seeing that I specialized in "X", you're more likely to think I specialized in some arcane form of crystal healing than the work I actually did.

My other AOSs sound fine, even semi-impressive to the layman, and so don't really concern me. This one, however....

So, two quick and related questions:

1. Am I right to think that my AOSs at least would still remain when listing my PhD on a non-academic CV/resume? Or just "PhD in field X"? [(The question on CV for leaving academia didn't provide too much specific guidance here.)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/cv-for-leaving-academia-after-phd)
2. Is it ethical to leave one of my AOSs off of the CV, assuming I leave the others untouched? In a sense it is misrepresenting what I did during my PhD, since I really did a lot of work in all three of these areas. On the other hand, listing this troublesome AOS might misrepresent what I did even more--- crystal healing and such.

Comment: Can you expand AOS here please, what does it stand for?

Comment: @FionaTaylorGorringe I would guess it's area of study, but its not very clear

Comment: @FionaTaylorGorringe Sorry, AOS is Area of Specialization. Didn't realize it wasn't a standard abbreviation.

Comment: So, what's an "Area of Specialization" (with capital letters)?  Is that different from "Research Interests"?  Surely there's more than one phrase to describe what your research is about?

Answer (score 6):

This seems like an obvious opportunity to briefly explain yourself on your CV by listing the formal names but then stating what that actually means in parentheses. As an example:

```
PhD, Some Named Institution (2007-Present)
Areas of Concentration:
 - Science thing 1
 - Science thing 2
 - Crystal healing sounding thing (Chemical Engineering)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying for jobs in industry or consulting, your Area of Specialization is much less important than the *skills* you have developed and your *proven record of performance* (producing results, completing projects, writing and publishing papers).  You could omit your Area of Specialization completely and just list your major and your skills, e.g.:

- PhD in Biochemistry. Skills: Experiment design and analysis, statistical analysis, computational modeling of protean evolution.